# edit XamDataGrid header

Tags: c#, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I want to edit a xamdatagrid so it looks like this

|updates     |

|passed | failed |

|  1    |   0    |

|  0    |   1    |

(My spacing is bad, but you get the idea ) 
I want to set up this template on the xamdatagrid and bind it to a dataset.
Is this possible? and in case it is possible where can I find a good example in c#? I keep finding bad and incomplete examples.

Comment: What is this ? Header?

Comment: Assuming that the "updates" is a common header for the "passed" and "failed" columns, then there is an example of something similar in the Infragistics blogs: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/alex_fidanov/archive/2010/06/02/howto-common-headers-in-the-xamdatagrid.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to create Field `LabelPresenterStyle`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:LabelPresenter}" x:Key="PassedFailedLabelPresenterStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:LabelPresenter}">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="passed | failed" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use it like

```
<igWPF:Field Name="Hired" Width="Auto" LabelPresenterStyle="{StaticResource PassedFailedLabelPresenterStyle}">
```

Comment: can you provide an example in c#?

Comment: Where do I put the style? can you put the complete xaml for this example?

Comment: You need to put this in inside your page xaml resources tag.